# Tensorflow lite crashing on android at native library libtensorflowlite_jni.so with code 11

Tags: android, background, native, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to run a tensorflow lite model in the background (while the app is closed) quite frequently (once every few minutes).
After the app has run for several hours I got this error message `signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)`.
I am aware that there are other people who have received similar issues, but after trying every solution I could find, I think that this might be a different issue.

## Google Play Console Crash Log

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.DD.GooglePlay <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000001cf138  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000001cef98  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000001c75ec  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000828b0  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000822dc  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000b2ba4  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000b8470  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000b70a0  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000000b13a8  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000001dd640  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 00000000001e0414  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000)
  #00  pc 000000000004af50  /data/app/~~PXyjTXZK6uVX_JbQzF-CNA==/com.DD.GooglePlay-qOnVNcJEpWKOgoYLG3cmFQ==/base.apk!libtensorflowlite_jni.so (offset 0xe52000) (Java_org_tensorflow_lite_NativeInterpreterWrapper_run+32)
  #00  pc 000000000013ded4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+148)
  #00  pc 0000000002023f64  /memfd:jit-cache (org.tensorflow.lite.NativeInterpreterWrapper.run+436)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 000000000030c254  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #00  pc 000000000030736c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+884)
  #00  pc 000000000063b0d4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+868)
  #00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 000000000031b136  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex (org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs+10)
  #00  pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440)
  #00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 000000000031b114  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex (org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.run+36)
  #00  pc 000000000063b310  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1440)
  #00  pc 000000000012e814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 000000000000f884  [anon:dalvik-classes3.dex (com.DD.GooglePlay.TensorFlowImageClassifier.recognizeImage+36)
  #00  pc 000000000063cca4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1840)
  #00  pc 000000000012ea14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #00  pc 000000000000c30a  [anon:dalvik-classes3.dex (com.DD.GooglePlay.PhotoTaker.delete+334)
  #00  pc 00000000002fed48  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.18441993989064323955)+268)
  #00  pc 0000000000629a84  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+796)
  #00  pc 000000000013dff8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+88)
  #00  pc 00000000020098e8  /memfd:jit-cache (com.DD.GooglePlay.PhotoTaker$3.run+6344)
  #00  pc 0000000000134564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #00  pc 0000000000198e94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+204)
  #00  pc 0000000000532198  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+104)
  #00  pc 0000000000533398  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JValue art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues<art::ArtMethod*>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, art::ArtMethod*, jvalue const*)+440)
  #00  pc 00000000005808b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+1272)
  #00  pc 00000000000b6374  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050fa4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

## Attempted Solutions

I tried to change the tensorflow version according to [this](https://github.com/inaturalist/react-native-inat-camera/issues/51). Additionally, I tried changing the tensorflow implementation the way they did [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48697).

Comment: did you find the solution for this?

Comment: I think it was due to a memory leak I had, but I am still having crashes that remain unexplained (with no log crash to examine), and tensorflow might be the reason for those crashes.

Comment: did you tired this one https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48697#issuecomment-826589092

Comment: Yes, it didn't work for me, if you have the exact same problem as I had, I think you should check if you a memory problam (not necessarily at tensorflow)

Comment: Memory problems like what could be the reason from memory and how?

Comment: I had some native memory leaks that occurred due to the use of face detection library.

Answer (score 1):

anyone has solved the above? I get the same thing while trying to run the model in the background on a physical device.
I have tried all the solution i could find on internet but with no success.

Comment: As far as I remember, the problem I was receiving wasn't at tensorflow, it was a memory leak occurred on other part of my code. So I recommend you to check wheather you have a memory leak somewhere in your code.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).